# react inline style backgroundImage not shown

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to load a background image in a react component. The image will ultimately vary so I am doing this with an inline style as follows:

```
const imageFilename = '../../../assets/img/picture.jpg';
<div className="auth-page" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${imageFilename}` , backgroundColor: '#cccccc'}}>
```

In chrome devtools I can see the style element which looks correct but no file is visible - I do see the background color though.

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(../../../assets/img/picture.jpg);
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

If I use a normal css file with background-image using the same path and filename the image is shown :

```
.auth-page {
  padding-top: 10vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(../assets/img/full-screen-image-5.jpg);
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Why does this not work using inline style (I remove background-image and background-color from the auth-page css style)?

Comment: First you need to import a image as component. 
Second you are missing  `)` at   `url(${imageFilename})`
Third add css property `Height, Width, background-position, background-size, background-repeat`
that's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the image.

```
import imageFilename from '../../../assets/img/picture.jpg';
```

Comment: That fixed the problem but how do I do an import programmatically? I need to lookup the filename in a database and then import that file from the assets/img directory.

Comment: dynamic photos will load without an import as long as they are in a public location.  If you are using create react app here is there docs on using a public folder https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/.  if you are using a cdn you can just load it like you are doing - style={{backgroundImage: `url(https://placehold.co/600x400)`}}>.

Comment: You can also dynamic import if needed - https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import

Comment: Ok so I've created an images directory in my public folder and am settting my filename as follows :   const imageFilename = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/full-screen-image-5.jpg";     but I don't see any background image!

Comment: console.log(imageFilename) and make sure the path is correct - it should be something like /images/full-screen-image-5.jpg. You can cut and paste it in your url to make sure it's correct ie localhost:3000/images/full-screen-image-5.jpg. Did you restart your server after creating the ENV path?

Comment: Solved the problem Sean W.! I place images in the public directory but also needed to change the filesize limit in webpack.config.dev.js. My file is 120KB in size and the limit was set to 10000. Changing that to 200000 fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

You are missing `)` here: `url(${imageFilename}`

**Try:**

```
import Img from  '../../../assets/img/picture.jpg';

<div className="auth-page" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${Img})` , backgroundColor: '#cccccc'}}>
```

Answer (score 2):

**First Problem**

Width and height have to be given along with the background image when the background image shows.

**Second Problem**

You are missing ) here: backgroundImage: `url(${imageFilename}`

***Demo :-***

```
    const imageFilename = ../../../assets/img/picture.jpg';
    <div className="auth-page" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${imageFilename})` , backgroundColor: '#cccccc', width: "100%", height: "100vh"}}></div>
```

Comment: Even with those changes the image was not appearing. Turned out that I needed to actually also import the image (as proposed by Sean W) which is annoying because that makes it difficult to do programmatically. So still not quite the solution I'm looking for. Is there any way to do an import programmatically?